Qual a função gramatical de "eu" na frase "Isso é tão eu!"?
Basicamente é o que está no título, eu acabei de ver num programa de perguntas e respostas qual a função gramatical de "Eu", e a resposta esperada era pronome. Porém dentre as alternativas tinha adjetivo, e eu pensei nessa frase do título na qual "Eu" parece desempenhar a função de adjetivo. Estou certo?

Em inglês temos a expressão "It's so me" que, dependendo do contexto, pode equivaler ao "Isso é a minha cara".

Na frase acima, "tão eu" exerce a função de predicativo do sujeito. "Eu", nesse caso, sofre um processo de derivação imprópria, funcionando como adjetivo (sinônimo de "parecido comigo").
